# Unable to mount NFS in Pop OS when NAS server has no Internet access

Tags: nfs

That very weird behavior seems to be related to firewall. When I apply filtering rule to prevent XigmaNAS from accessing the Internet, then Pop OS host cannot mount that share. All traffic passes as it should between host and the server, which are located in different subnets, WebGUI and ping works as intended on that server, I can even mount samba shares but not NFS.

My current network setup:

- router, I basically removed server subnet from NAT standard ACL
- layer 3 switch
- default static route between switch and router

I tried to mount that share from Centos 7 but I get the same error: `mount.nfs: Connection timed out`

Edit:

the ACL on the router before modification:

```
access-list 2 permit 10.20.0.0 0.0.0.127
```

and after:

```
access-list 2 deny 10.20.0.68
access-list 2 permit 10.20.0.0 0.0.0.63
access-list 2 permit 10.20.0.64 0.0.0.15
```

server is located in 10.20.0.64 subnet with IP 10.20.0.68

Why it would affect routing between host and server on the L3 switch while the rule aplies to external interface? TBH I don't need a router to perform routing on my LAN and I don't think it's the networking issue. On top of that I deployed another Centos in the same subnet as the XigmaNAS server, getting the same error.

Comment: Could you edit your question to add some more detail about the problem and the environment?  For example, just to start with:  "When I apply filtering rule to prevent XigmaNAS from accessing the Internet, then Pop OS host cannot mount that share".  So, *exactly* what filtering rule did you apply, and where did you apply it?  Can other hosts that are not Pop OS mount the NFS share from the NAS, or does this problem only affect Pop OS?

Comment: I note that you edited the question - thanks!  We still don't know quite what you did with the filtering rule - you mentioned "I basically removed server subnet from NAT standard ACL", but we don't know what that ACL looks like.  I am assuming the NFS mount did work before you changed the ACL.  Therefore, I'd conclude that either the client can't successfully get packets to the server, or the server can't successfully get packets to the client, or both...  In other words, though your intent was to block Internet access by the NAS, it seems that your filtering is too broad and drops all traffic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned up that XigmaNAS do DNS lookup for NFS shares, and this is done on client startup. Not sure what is the point of this mechanism, but to fix that I had to remove external DNS IP form Xigma config. Now shares are accessible even when server has no Internet connection.